# Passing 2D array as 1D array in a Knapsack program

Tags: c++, arrays, stack-overflow, knapsack-problem

I am writing the program of a knapsack problem in which we need to find out the minimum cost to achieve the target or print impossible if otherwise it is not achievable.
I am passing the 2-D array of cost and Value as a pointer to 1-D array. The code is running fine for the cases when the target value is around 5000. But for higher numbers the program is getting force closed. What is the error due to which it is not working for larger values?

> **[Question]**
> First line is the number of testcases. The weight of the
> empty cup, E, and the weight of the filled cup of juice, F, are given
> separately as blanks for the first line of each test case. (1 ≤ E ≤ F
> ≤ 10,000). Target = F-E. The number of kinds of juice that is used, N,
> is given for the next line. (1 ≤ N ≤ 500) From the next line through
> to the amount of N lines, the unit price and weight of each juice is
> given separately as blanks. The unit price of juice is positive number
> ≤ 50,000; and the weight is positive number ≤ 10,000.
>
> **Input:**
> 1
> 10 110
> 2
> 1 1
> 30 50
>
> **Output:**
> 60

Code:

```
int calculate( int variable, int* input, int n)
{
int array[n+1][variable+1];
for(int j=0; j<variable+1; j++)
    array[0][j]=100000000;
for(int i=1; i<n+1; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<variable+1; j++)
    {
        if(j==0)
            array[i][j]=0;
        else if(j<input[n+i-1])
            array[i][j]=array[i-1][j];
        else
            array[i][j]=min(array[i-1][j], input[i-1]+array[i][j-input[n+i-1]]);
    }
}
return array[n][variable];
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int testcase;
cin>>testcase;
for(int t=0; t<testcase; t++)
{
    int cup1=0, cup2=0, n=0, result=0;
    cin>>cup1>>cup2>>n;
    int input[2][n];
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
            cin>>input[i][j];
    }
    int variable=cup2-cup1;
    result=calculate(variable, (int*) input, n);
    if(result<100000000)
        cout<<result<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"impossible"<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would have properly formatted your code, but since you forgot to mention which programming language you use, and why this feels like we're doing your homework, but should care nevertheless, I think it's up to you to add the programming language as tag, and format the whole code as code (by clicking on a single button).

Comment: Nice! now you have the C++ tag, and we know which programming language you want to use. Would you still mind formatting the whole code as code? that, together with proper indenting, would greatly increase value of your question.

Comment: I have formatted the complete code for better understanding. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
result=calculate(variable, (int*) input, n);
```

should be

```
result=calculate(variable, input[0], n);
```

Review 2D array structures.

For larger values of n, you may be running out of stack space. You likely have to use new. If you need to use new, you need to allocate a 1D array if you want to use it as a 1D array, otherwise it won't be in contiguous memory.

Comment: I made the suitable changes in function calling but still it is not working. I even tried to declare

int input[2][100000] in the main function before taking input from user.

Can you please elaborate me the way to make the dynamic memory allocation using new in this particular example. I didn't catch it. As i need to take data in  2D format and then pass it as 1D.